# Why do my Android unit tests fail when run together, but pass when run individually?

Tags: android, mockito

Here is my whole test class:

```
@RunWith(JUnit4::class)
class ExplorerRemoteImplTest {

    // Mocks
    private val mockDatabase = mock<FirebaseFirestore>(
            defaultAnswer = RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS
    )
    private val mockQuerySnapshot = mock<QuerySnapshot>()
    private val mockQuerySnapshotTask = mock<Task<QuerySnapshot>>()

    // Class under test
    private lateinit var explorerRemoteImpl: ExplorerRemoteImpl

    // Others
    private val poiList = listOf(TestDataFactory.makePoiRepo(),TestDataFactory.makePoiRepo())

    @Before
    fun setup(){
        //create instance of class under test
        explorerRemoteImpl = ExplorerRemoteImpl(mockDatabase)


        // Step #1 return the query Task on get().
        whenever(mockDatabase.collection(ArgumentMatchers.anyString()).orderBy(ArgumentMatchers.anyString()).get()).thenReturn(mockQuerySnapshotTask)

        // Step #2 return a queryTask when registering the listener
        whenever(mockQuerySnapshotTask.addOnCompleteListener(anyOrNull()))
                .thenReturn(mockQuerySnapshotTask)

        // Step #3 task IS successful is stubbed

        // Step #4 the results of the task is a QuerySnapshot
        whenever(mockQuerySnapshotTask.result).thenReturn(mockQuerySnapshot)

        // Step #5 QuerySnapshot = is empty or not is stubbed

        // Step #6 when we try to convert snapShot to objects
        whenever(mockQuerySnapshot.toObjects(PoiRepository::class.java)).thenReturn(poiList)
    }

    private fun stubQuerySnapshotIsEmpty(boolean: Boolean){
        whenever(mockQuerySnapshot.isEmpty).thenReturn(boolean)
    }

    private fun stubQueryTaskIsSuccessful(boolean: Boolean){
        whenever(mockQuerySnapshotTask.isSuccessful).thenReturn(boolean)
    }

    @After
    fun onEnd(){
        Mockito.reset(mockQuerySnapshotTask)
        Mockito.reset(mockDatabase)
        Mockito.reset(mockQuerySnapshot)
    }

    @Test
    fun getPoisCompletes() {

        // GIVEN
        stubQueryTaskIsSuccessful(true)
        stubQuerySnapshotIsEmpty(false)

        val testObserver = explorerRemoteImpl.getPois().test()

        // Trigger callback reply
        // see: https://fernandocejas.com/2014/04/08/unit-testing-asynchronous-methods-with-mockito/
        val captor = argumentCaptor<OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>>()
        verify(mockQuerySnapshotTask).addOnCompleteListener(captor.capture())
        captor.lastValue.onComplete(mockQuerySnapshotTask)

        verify(mockQuerySnapshotTask, times(1)).addOnCompleteListener(anyOrNull())

        // THEN
        testObserver
                .assertNoErrors()
                .assertValueCount(1)
                .assertComplete()
    }

    @Test
    fun getPoisCompletesOnEmptyQuerySnapshot() {

        // GIVEN
        stubQueryTaskIsSuccessful(true)
        stubQuerySnapshotIsEmpty(true)

        val testObserver = explorerRemoteImpl.getPois().test()

        // Trigger callback reply
        // see: https://fernandocejas.com/2014/04/08/unit-testing-asynchronous-methods-with-mockito/
        val captor = argumentCaptor<OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>>()
        verify(mockQuerySnapshotTask).addOnCompleteListener(captor.capture())
        captor.firstValue.onComplete(mockQuerySnapshotTask)

        // THEN
        testObserver
                .assertNoErrors()
                .assertValueCount(0)
                .assertComplete()

        Mockito.verify(mockQuerySnapshotTask, times(1)).addOnCompleteListener(anyOrNull())
    }

    @Test
    fun getPoisErrorsOnNoSuccessQuerySnapshot() {

        // GIVEN
        stubQueryTaskIsSuccessful(false)
        stubQuerySnapshotIsEmpty(true)

        val testObserver = explorerRemoteImpl.getPois().test()

        // Trigger callback reply
        val captor = argumentCaptor<OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>>()
        verify(mockQuerySnapshotTask).addOnCompleteListener(captor.capture())
        captor.firstValue.onComplete(mockQuerySnapshotTask)

        Mockito.verify(mockQuerySnapshotTask, times(1)).addOnCompleteListener(anyOrNull())

        // task Exception not mocked, so unknown is passed via Elvis operator
        testObserver.assertError(UnknownError::class.java)
    }
}
```

There are 3 unit tests and they all pass when run separately, but when I run the whole test class my 2nd and 3rd tests fail with an error that reads:

```
Wanted but not invoked:
task.addOnCompleteListener(
    <Capturing argument>
);
-> at com.loc8r.seattleexplorer.remote.ExplorerRemoteImplTest.getPoisCompletesOnEmptyQuerySnapshot(ExplorerRemoteImplTest.kt:113)
Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.
```

I've tried everything I can think of to resolve the problem:

1. I moved my class under test instantiation into the @Before function.
2. I tried creating an @After function and called Mockito.reset on my mocks.

I should mention that I'm using the nhaarman.mockitokotlin2 library and it's argumentCaptor.

Any clues as to why these tests passing when run alone but failing when run together as a class?

Comment: I also faced this situation earlier. Check that you have global variables that can be changed in tests. Probably you can reset them in `@Before` or `@After`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to avoid using a single, shared instance of the Class Under Tests which is `ExplorerRemoteImpl` in you case? Try to create a new instance for every single test method.

Actually I am facing exactly the same issue that you have described above, but I cannot re-instantiate my Class Under Test, because I try to test a singleton.

**Update:**
I have refactored the implementation of my singleton so for testing I can instantiate the Class Under Test for every single test method. The issue does no longer occur.